# Use external JavaScript function inside JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, function

I have created a JavaScript file. This JavaScript file uses a function from an external JavaScript file. For example:

```
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
    autoplay: {
        delay: 5000,
        disableOnInteraction: true,
    },
});
```

The Swiper function in this example is coming from an external JavaScript file. How can I link the JavaScript file on my PC to this external JavaScript file. The external JavaScript file is found on the web and I do not want to download this file to my PC.

I have tried including both Script statements inside the HTML file which has not worked. I have also tried including a Script statement inside the JavaScript file, which did not work.

I have tried using this line:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="external-javascript-file.js"></script>
```

I have also tried using the same line in JavaScript

```
<script src="external-javascript-file.js"></script>
```

I have also tried using these lines in JavaScript

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "external-javascript-file.js";
document.head.prepend(script);
```

When I use the above lines in JavaScript, there is no error message. Instead, there is the warning: Could not load content for link, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

However, when I access the link directly, the code is displayed correctly.

I have copied the JavaScript code and written it inline with the HTML code. When I do this, it works correctly. However, I want my JavaScript code to be external to the HTML code.

Comment: *"I have tried including both Script statements inside the HTML file which has not worked."*: that's the way to do it. Show your attempt if it didn't work, and explain how you detected it didn't work (information about error message...)

Comment: The traditional way is `<script src=....` Of course, you need to include it **before** your script

Comment: Swap the two `<script>` lines. You can't use something in `script.js` before it's been declared in `external-javascript-file.js`

Comment: I have tried this, it does not work. When I use the JavaScript code inline with the HTML, it works correctly. This issue only occurs when the JavaScript is written externally

Comment: Judging on the error you get the file could not be found. Check for the correct url and if the file is exposed to the internet correctly.

Comment: Yes, the url is correct. When I use the same url in the HTML file using inline JavaScript, it works as expected.

Comment: _"I have tried this, it does not work"_... tried **what**, exactly? Please [edit] your question to show what you changed. Also, I see no reason for you to obfuscate the external JS URL. You might as well include the real value in your question

Comment: I have written down what I have tried

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If a JavaScript file is using a class from a different JavaScript file, the JavaScript file containing the class should be linked to your HTML file before linking the JavaScript file which contains the class to your HTML file.